# Two Condition While Loop Not Working

Tags: r

I'm experimenting with a dice rolling simulation. The purpose of the simulation is to generate  a vector of six values, each element of which are the sum of 3 six sided dice. I'm trying to use a while loop to reflect two conditions: the sum of the vector should be greater than a provided value AND the the maximum element value should be greater than a threshold.

I have tried using `&` and `&&`, changing the order of arguments, etc... but with each iteration the code only executes one condition, that the total be greater than the provided value.

I have read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297582/how-to-have-two-conditions-in-a-while-loop), but it hasn't helped.

The code:

```
random.stats=function(threshold,roll){
  require(random)
  temp=rep(0,6)
  j=0
  while(sum(temp)<threshold && max(temp)<roll){
    for(i in 1:6){
      temp[i]=sum(sort(randomNumbers(n=5,min=1,max=6,col=1),
                       decreasing=TRUE)[1:3])
    }
    j=j+1
  }
  return(list(rolls=temp,total=sum(temp),required.iterations=j))
}
```

A sample problematic function call is `random.stats(70,18)`. I always get a total value greater than 70, but obtain the 18 only by chance, about 5% of the time.

The for loops are used to weight the rolls, simulating rolling 5 six sided dice and using only the 3 highest values.

Can anybody assist in troubleshooting this flow control issue?

EDIT: Probability densities for each condition separately:

[image: Probability of 5 six sided dice subtracting the two lowest]

[image: Cumulative probability of vector sum]

Comment: I am using R version 3.1.0 FWIW

Comment: So you're saying you've got a result from this function where `sum(rolls)<70` and `max(rools)<18`? I didn't see that when I ran it. Are you surprised by the number of iterations? or the fact that it's unlikely to get an 18 and not have a `total>70`? You might want to think about calculating the probability of those events actually happening.

Comment: I want the while loop to stop when both conditions are true. The supplied values could be anything, but using 18 for `max(rolls)` is the easiest case to spot a failure with. I'm getting only `sum(rolls)>=70` to return `TRUE`. I would expect `required.iterations` to be on the order of 20-30 for this case. It is also quite likely to have `total>70` without `max(rolls)==18`.

Comment: @GSee `j` is returned in the result so you know how many times you looped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong condition in your while loop. Consider the case

```
roll = c(14,  17,  14,  10,  15, 14)
sum(roll) = 84
max(roll) = 17
```

Right now your while will only run if both `sum<70` and `max<18` but observe

```
sum(roll)<70 & max(roll)<18 
    == FALSE & TRUE 
    == FALSE
```

so your loop won't run again. It only runs while `TRUE`. What you really want is an "OR" (`|`)

```
while ( sum(temp)<threshold | max(temp)<roll )
```

Comment: Using `|` definitely works, but I don't understand why. The while loop continues so long as the argument is `TRUE`. I would expect the behavior I was getting in the OP using `|` rather than with `&` or `&&`. The flow control seems backwards to me.

Comment: @scs217 Take some time to write out the truth tables as I did above. And remember `while` only runs when it's check return `TRUE` and `&` requires both elements to be `TRUE`

Comment: I see your point. I didn't know I could have the terminal evaluate those logical operators directly until just now. Knowing that I can enter `>TRUE | FALSE`, etc... directly will allow me to troubleshoot most other logic evaluation discrepancies I may run into. Thanks again!

Comment: +1 MrFlick. @scs217, another way to think about this that might be more intuitive is to loop when the values are NOT as you want them to be: while(!(sum(temp)>threshold & max(temp)>roll)). This is logically equivalent to the OR that MrFlick has suggested. Check out De Morgan's law at http://www.csm.ornl.gov/~sheldon/ds/sec1.1.html

Comment: +1. Just so you know, you can accomplish this in base R: `random.stats <- function(threshold,roll){
  temp <- rep(0,6)
  j <- 0
  while(sum(temp)<threshold | max(temp)<roll){
    temp <- sapply(1:6,function(x) sum(sample(1:6,3,replace=TRUE)))
    j <- j + 1
  }
  return(list(rolls=temp,total=sum(temp),required.iterations=j))
}`

Comment: @userNAN Yes, I have used both. I don't personally mistrust Mersenne Twister, grabbing data from random.org was used in this example for a friend of mine to satisfy an (unfounded) concern.