# while() in R with two conditions

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

In trying to understand the syntax behind `while()` commands in R, I come to a problem introducing two conditions. There is a [post on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21297673/4089351), but it doesn't seem to work.

The toy code is self-explanatory, and very simple:

```
> x = sample(c("Y", "M", "_"))
> y = sample(c("O", "U","E", "S", "H"))
> 
> while(paste(x, collapse ="") != "MY_") x = sample(x)
> paste(x, collapse = "")
[1] "MY_"
> 
> while(paste(y, collapse ="") != "HOUSE") y = sample(y)
> paste(y, collapse = "")
[1] "HOUSE"
> 
> while(paste(x, collapse ="") != "MY_" && paste(y, collapse ="") != "HOUSE") x = sample(x); y = sample(y)
> paste(c(x, y), collapse = "")
[1] "MY_OEHSU"
```

Wrong answer! The expected answer is "MY_HOUSE".

Why isn't `&&` doing the trick?

---

Thanks to the comments below! If there is a formal answer I will erase this edit to credit where credit is due. Otherwise, and in case it helps other people, this is the correct code:

```
> x = sample(c("Y", "M", "_"))
> y = sample(c("O", "U","E", "S", "H"))
> 
> while(paste(x, collapse ="") != "MY_") x = sample(x)
> paste(x, collapse = "")
[1] "MY_"
> 
> while(paste(y, collapse ="") != "HOUSE") y = sample(y)
> paste(y, collapse = "")
[1] "HOUSE"
> 
> while(paste(x, collapse ="") != "MY_" || paste(y, collapse ="") != "HOUSE") {x = sample(x); y = sample(y)}
> paste(c(x, y), collapse = "")
[1] "MY_HOUSE"
```

Comment: use `{x = sample(x); y = sample(y)}`

Comment: @HubertL Thank you. Your answer works like a charm. The double bar syntax is not working well. Want to post a formal answer?

Comment: Let's say it's a typo...

Comment: It could also be framed as `not ( x is TRUE && y is TRUE)` - i.e. - `!(paste(x, collapse ="") == "MY_" && paste(y, collapse ="") == "HOUSE")`